# How to pivot data with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys good morning.

I have this data set:

data = {'Dates':['2017-11-08','2017-11-09','2017-11-10','2017-11-13','2017-11-14','2017-11-15',
'2017-11-08','2017-11-09','2017-11-10','2017-11-13','2017-11-14','2017-11-15',
'2017-11-08','2017-11-09','2017-11-10','2017-11-13','2017-11-14','2017-11-15'],
'Category_data':["A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"],
'Values_data':["1","3","4","6","1","1","6","1","1","5","3","1","6","1","1","6","1","1"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

and I am trying to pivot it so that my columns become: Category_data, and Dates become the index, with values_data becoming values. The challenge is I get error duplicate values. So I'm wondering if there is a way to aggregate the data on Dates?

Objective output:

| Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-11-08 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

etc....

Comment: Use `pivot_table`

Comment: The challenge is I get the error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: hmm, so used `pivot`, not `pivot_table`

Comment: still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: for me working nice, `df['Values_data'] = df['Values_data'].astype(int)

df = df.pivot_table(index='Dates', columns='Category_data', values='Values_data')`

Comment: The data set was a sample turns out really stupid mistake.... I actually did have duplicate values in the dataframe. .pivot works nicely. Thank you!